# Subset data with limited row number

Tags: r, group-by, subset

I have large data frame which contains customers data. I'm trying to activate some algorithm over each customer, but facing performence troubles.

Because of that I'd like to subset the data over each customer, but taking only the last most updated 'n' observations.

Important issues:

- I'm running my algorithm for each new observation (meaning, I need a "new" subset for each new observation)
- I'm holding a history of all customers (this is the "large data frame" mentioned above) which refresh once a day

I thought of doing something like(and then selecting the `tail` or `head` or some other, faster, method):

```
dfrm %>% group_by(cust_id) %>% .[order(-.[,1]),]
```

where my first column is the date and time the cutomer took his purchase in the following format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` (of structure `POSIXct`); but I'm getting an error of

> Error in `-POSIXt` (left) : unary '-' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Aside of solving my problem, I'll be happy to hear any other ideas to handle my problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `arrange`? and perhaps `slice` or `filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested you could do:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time() + rnorm(5)), cust_id = rnorm(5))
dfrm %>% group_by(cust_id) %>% arrange(date) %>% slice(1)
```

To arrange it in different order use `arrange(desc(date))` not `-`

As you asked in comment regarding filtering and 100 latest records:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time() + rnorm(5)), cust_id = rnorm(5), hour = 1:5)
dfrm %>% group_by(cust_id) %>% arrange(date) %>% filter(hour == 1) %>% slice(1:100)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I just need to check my performence with this new method :)

Comment: With your premission I'll ask you one more thing.. After I'm arranging my historical data: `groups <- dfrm %>% group_by(cust_id)%>%arrange(date)`.. I'm trying to pull out the customer data (last 100 observations) which took place between specific hours (`hour` field).. I'm trying to do it using `filter` with no success. Can you please help me with that? Thank you in advance

Comment: I added a few lines with filtering and slice for last 100 observations.